# Hide <li> using a condition with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, list, hide

I have html

```
<ul>
<li>option1: blue </li>
<li>option2: red</li>
<li>option3: </li>
<li>option4: green</li>
<li>option5: </li>
</ul>
```

What I would like to do is hide the li if after the option: there are no characters/value.

I have limited knowledge using query and I have not yet found an example that would help me find the solution. It would be possible for me to enclose the values red,green etc if necessary.

Is this possible to accomplish with Jquery?

Comment: Why not change your view so that options with no value are not rendered? Hiding redunant options is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
$("ul li").each(function() {
    var optionText = $(this).text().split(":")[1];
    if (optionText.trim() == "")
        $(this).hide();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/44qeG/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#the-list li').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (!text.match(/option\d+: .+?/g)) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Assuming your list has `id="the-list"`, of course.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edJy4/

The regex pattern explained: The text contains a string of characters which begins with "option" followed by one or more digits, a colon, a space, and then one or more characters. If the `li` does *not* contain such a string, the `li` is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

This one uses regex:

```
$(function(){
    $('li').each(function(){
        if($(this).text().search(/option\d:\s\s*$/) == 0){
            $(this).hide();   
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pT8s2/

Comment: Thank you for this solution this was just the ticket!